# jQuery Datatables reorder columns from ajax source

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the jQuery plug-in [Datatables](http://datatables.net/), is it possible to change the order of the columns without changing the source data?

Here is an [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tVa4k/) of what I have now.

Currently it is LicenseNumber, FirstName, LastName
I would like it to be  FirstName, LastName, LicenseNumber

Is there a parameter I can add to the datatable setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not entirely sure I've understood the question, but this might be of use:

(1) DataTables has a ColReorder plugin.

http://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/

In the link above, you can select a column with your mouse and then drag the column to a different position in the table.

In another example of using the ColReorder plugin, you can predefine your 
column order, as stated on the datatables site:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColReorder/examples/predefined.html

> ColReorder provides the ability to specify a column ordering which is
>   not that of the HTML (which typically you will want) through the
>   parameter oColReorder.aiOrder. This is an array of integers with the
>   column ordering you want.

---

(2) I believe you could also make use of **aoColumnDefs** and **[mDataProp](http://datatables.net/ref#mDataProp)** if your data was an array of objects. (also see http://datatables.net/usage/columns)

```
...
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { "mDataProp": "FirstName", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
    { "mDataProp": "LastName", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
    { "mDataProp": "LicenseNumber", "aTargets": [ 2 ] }
],
...
```

Comment: The aoColumnDefs will work if I give it a json object, thanks!